# Is it possible to have a front end tag entry form that is responsive? How?

Tags: solspace-tag

I'm trying to create a front-end channel form using bootstrap and I have a Tag Module field in it. I'd like to make the field responsive so it could be used on a phone. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS rules that override the rules applied to the Tag widget.

If you don't want to use the Tag widget, you could have a simple textarea form with `name="your_tag_field_name"`:

`<textarea name="your_tag_field_name"></textarea>`

This lets you customize the form field the way you want (eg. make it responsive). Each tag would have to be on their own line in this case.